# Fiscal budget: spending in real vs nominal terms

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, fiscal-policy

What does it mean in the context of a budget to “freeze spending in real terms”? And how would this differ from freezing spending in “nominal terms”?

I am looking to understand how this would be implemented and the broader macro relevance

Answer (score 2):

If there is no inflation then the two phrases would mean the same

But if there is positive inflation, then *"freezing spending in nominal terms"* would involve spending the same amount of money, and since prices are rising, would involve buying less.  Meanwhile *"freezing spending in real terms"* would involve spending an increased amount of money corresponding to the increase in prices, with the effect after taking price changes into account of buying the same amount.